# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'tabIndex') in react js

Tags: reactjs

```
const skipInputRef =useRef();
useEffect(
    () => {
        
        skipInputRef.current.tabIndex = -1;

    },
    [  ]
);
<div className="input__country" ref={skipInputRef}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

skipInputRef initially undefined

```js
const skipInputRef =useRef();
useEffect(() => { 
        if(skipInputRef.current) skipInputRef.current.tabIndex = -1;
    },[]);
<div className="input__country" ref={skipInputRef}>
</div>
```